# teamcity-messages for gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci

I'm using pytest with gitlab and I'm wondering if there's a way to automatically parse test results in the pipeline, so that I don't have to go manually in the terminal output and search for test names that have failed. Teamcity has such a feature by using teamcity-messages.

Does anybody know if such a feature is available for gitlab as well?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `teamcity-messages`, but Gitlab parses the JUnit report (should you keep one as artifact) and shows the results in the merge request view. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMGdr.png) in the end. Is this something you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for, how can I get this? What do you mean with "keep one as artifact"?

Comment: Just let `pytest` write a JUnit report and keep it as an artifact, that should be enough. IIRC this feature is available in the community edition already. I will add an answer with a sample config shortly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Test summary in Merge Request view

Gitlab supports parsing and rendering test results from a JUnit report file. The reserved word for that is [`artifacts:reports:junit`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsreportsjunit). Here is an example CI config that generates a JUnit report on a `pytest` run and makes it available to Gitlab:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - pytest --junitxml=report.xml
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit: report.xml
```

Here is what the results would look like rendered in the Merge Request view:

[image: gitlab-junit]

More info (and examples for other languages) can be found in Gitlab docs: [JUnit test reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html).

#### Preview feature: test summary in the Pipeline view

On the doc page linked above, you can also find a preview feature of an extra `Tests` card in the pipeline view:

[image: gitlab-junit-pipeline]

This feature is available since 12.5 and currently should be explicitly enabled by an admin via the `:junit_pipeline_view` flag.

#### Edit: your case

To sum up, I would rework the `pytest` invocation command and add the reports section to `artifacts` in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
test:
  script:
    - pytest -vv
      --cov=${ROOT_MODULE}
      --cov-branch
      --cov-report term-missing
      --cov-report xml:artifacts/coverage.xml
      --junitxml=artifacts/junit.xml

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifacts/coverage.xml
      - artifacts/junit.xml  # if you want the JUnit report to be also downloadable
    reports:
      junit: artifacts/junit.xml
```

Comment: That looks great. I think my problem is that I have a coverage report already. Can I have both at the same time? I have `pytest -vv --cov=${ROOT_MODULE} --cov-branch --junitxml=artifacts/coverage.xml` and then `artifacts: paths: - "./artifacts/coverage.xml`. Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: I don't think the option `--junitxml=artifacts/coverage.xml` does what you need - it is a plain JUnit report that is just named `coverage.xml`. If you want to generate the Cobertura-like XML report for coverage, pass the `--cov-report xml:artifacts/coverage.xml` instead.

Comment: Check the edit in the answer - it's not possible to properly render a YAML config in the comments.